# SQLite: Query to list

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables with:

Table1:

```
ID_Number | Description|
a         | abc
b         | cde
c         | fgh
```

Table2:

```
ID | Title         | value
a  | phone number  | 555-1234
a  | address       | somewhere USA
a  | mobile_number | 867-5309
b  | phone number  | ...
b  | address       | ...
b  | mobile_number | ...
```

I want to create a new table with all data that belong to each ID_number that exists in Table 2.

with the query I'm able to list all.

```
select Table1.ID_Number, Table2.ID from Table1, Table2 
where Table1_ID_number = Table2.ID))
order by ID_Number
```

But I would like to create a new table with:

```
Table3
    |ID | Description| ID_data
    a , abc, "Address_A_PhoneNumber_A_Mobile_Number_A"
    b , cde, "Address_B_PhoneNumber_B_Mobile_Number_B"
```

Is this possible with SQL???

Answer (score 1):

I needed to edit your question and add a third column to the second table containing values for the various types of information.  Without something like this, I'm afraid your question makes no sense.

We can aggregate by `ID` and pivot out the address and phone numbers into a single concatenated string.

```
SELECT
    t1.ID_Number,
    t1.Description
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.title = 'address'       THEN t2.value END) || '_' ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.title = 'phone number'  THEN t2.value END) || '_' ||
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.title = 'mobile_number' THEN t2.value END) AS ID_data
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.ID_Number = t2.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID_Number,
    t1.Description;
```